# Healthchecks on different port in Net core Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a standard Net core web application with an API. 
I'm trying to implement healthcheck, but want it to run on a different port.

In Configure:

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/health", 8000);
```

In ConfigureServices

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
```

By default, the api is accessible via:
https://localhost:44322/api/values

And I then expect the healthcheck to be accessible via: https://localhost:8000/health

The healh works good if I remove the port. Do I need some other configuration to setup the application to run on different ports?

Comment: Port `8000` has to be registered in the listening ports of your app. You can do it on `Program.cs` under `.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000/;http://localhost:8000/")`. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-by-port, or do it inside the `launchSettings.json`.

Comment: @jpgrassi works great. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as approved!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested, I'm creating an answer so future readers can benefit from.

The initial problem was because you were not registering the health check port `8000` in your app. There are two ways to do this.

1. By setting the port in `launchSettings.json` which is picked up by the [Environment Variables Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider)
2. Or as I suggested in the comments, call `UseUrls` in `Program.cs` and specify the HealthCheck port directly there, along with the ones for your app. Something like this:

```
return new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000/;http://localhost:8000")
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseStartup(startupType)
    .Build();
```

Where `5000` is your normal App port, and `8000` is the HealthCheck one.

Then inside `Configure` in `Startup.cs` you use the port directly:

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/health", port: 8000);
```

You can find all of this and more in the official docs: [Health checks in ASP.NET Core - Filtering by Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-by-port-1)

Comment: Quick note, ASPNET Core 6 now uses `.MapHealthChecks(...).RequireHost("*:8000")` now.

Comment: Did you find out how to prevent the application from also exposing all other routes on the healthcheck port? Following the example above, the healthcheck method works, but I also get all other services (swagger, MVC etc.) being exposed on the healthcheck port, which breaks my security model

Comment: @jpgrassi - I want to use a custom url with domainname:port for deploying to Production. Since Healthcheck is being deployed as a background service, how do I change localhost:8000 to something meaningful like <server-name>:host??